# Dynamic IP in one and static in other networks with docker compose

Tags: networking, docker-compose

What is correct syntax for dynamic address in one network and static in other network? (When container placed in 2 networks.)

Now my `docker-compose.yml` looks like this:

```
version: '2'
networks:
  default:
    driver: bridge
  vpn:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 10.1.2.0
services:
  openvpn:
    image: foo
    networks:
      - default
      - vpn
  app:
    image: bar
    networks:
      default:
        ipv4_address: 10.0.0.1/24
      vpn:
        ipv4_address: 10.1.2.3/24
```

It works, but I don't want to set ip addr in `default` network for `app` container to avoid conflicts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems it is enough to just remove static IP address declaration:

```
  app:
    image: bar
    networks:
      default:
      vpn:
        ipv4_address: 10.1.2.3/24
```

In this case in `default` network dynamic address will be set, and in `vpn` static one.